# How to handle "org/apache/log4j/Level" class used in 3rd-party jar when using log4j2?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

As we know, org/apache/log4j/Level is a log4j api, but not log4j2.

But in my case,hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.2 jar used Level class in its static code. So it will give a ClassNotFound exception if I use log4j2.

Anyway to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Log4j 1.x bridge.

For more information, See [Migrating from Log4j 1.x](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html).